# Simple jQuery expandable div's need to change the arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to toggle the arrows when a div is expanded see

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expandableCollapsibleDiv').click(function() {
var showElementDescription = $(this).find('ul');
   // var showElementDescription = $(this).parents('.expandableCollapsibleDiv').find('ul');
    if ($(showElementDescription).is(':visible')) {
      showElementDescription.hide("fast", "swing");
      $(this).find($('.fa')).removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
    } else {
      showElementDescription.show("fast", "swing");
      $(this).find($('.fa')).removeClass('fa-angle-up').addClass('fa-angle-down');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.expandableCollapsibleDiv i {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.expandableCollapsibleDiv ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  clear: both;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
  /* visibility: hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="expandableCollapsibleDiv">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
    <h3><a>NEW YORK</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Albany</a></li>
      <li><a>Buffalo</a></li>
      <li><a>Kingston</a></li>
      <li><a>Tonawanda</a></li>
      <li><a>Sherrill</a></li>
      <li><a>Sherrill</a></li>
      <li><a>Oneida</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="expandableCollapsibleDiv">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
    <h3><a>CALIFORNIA</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Alameda</a></li>
      <li><a>Bell</a></li>
      <li><a>Banning</a></li>
      <li><a>Campbell</a></li>
      <li><a>Fresno</a></li>
      <li><a>Galt</a></li>
      <li><a>Jackson</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="expandableCollapsibleDiv">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
    <h3><a>WASHINGTON</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Asotin</a></li>
      <li><a>Bellingham</a></li>
      <li><a>Bothell</a></li>
      <li><a>Camas</a></li>
      <li><a>Clarkston</a></li>
      <li><a>Cheney</a></li>
      <li><a>Newport</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem, on page load the div is set to display:none and not set with css visible. The arrow doesn't react as it should. I like the arrow to point down when the div is not expanded (hidden) and to point up if the div is expanded (visible).
Using visible:hidden didn't solve my problem as the div are using the space on the page.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Put the [mcve] **in** the question, not just linked. Please also refer to the formatting help (there was a bit orange **How to Format** box next to the question as you were typing with major things like now to mark up code as code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had used `.find()` incorrectly. Also `JQuery` library was not included in the JSFiddle, so I included that!.

**Note:** Initially the arrow should be `fa-angle-up` instead of `fa-angle-down`.

**Before:**

```
$(this).find($('.fa')).removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
```

**After:**

```
$(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expandableCollapsibleDiv').click(function() {
var showElementDescription = $(this).find('ul');
   // var showElementDescription = $(this).parents('.expandableCollapsibleDiv').find('ul');
    if ($(showElementDescription).is(':visible')) {
      showElementDescription.hide("fast", "swing");
      $(this).find($('.fa')).removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
    } else {
      showElementDescription.show("fast", "swing");
      $(this).find($('.fa')).removeClass('fa-angle-up').addClass('fa-angle-down');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.expandableCollapsibleDiv i {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.expandableCollapsibleDiv ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  clear: both;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
  /* visibility: hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="expandableCollapsibleDiv">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
    <h3><a>NEW YORK</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Albany</a></li>
      <li><a>Buffalo</a></li>
      <li><a>Kingston</a></li>
      <li><a>Tonawanda</a></li>
      <li><a>Sherrill</a></li>
      <li><a>Sherrill</a></li>
      <li><a>Oneida</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="expandableCollapsibleDiv">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
    <h3><a>CALIFORNIA</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Alameda</a></li>
      <li><a>Bell</a></li>
      <li><a>Banning</a></li>
      <li><a>Campbell</a></li>
      <li><a>Fresno</a></li>
      <li><a>Galt</a></li>
      <li><a>Jackson</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="expandableCollapsibleDiv">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
    <h3><a>WASHINGTON</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Asotin</a></li>
      <li><a>Bellingham</a></li>
      <li><a>Bothell</a></li>
      <li><a>Camas</a></li>
      <li><a>Clarkston</a></li>
      <li><a>Cheney</a></li>
      <li><a>Newport</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the feedback, updated my answer with the changes!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Will follow from the next question, Sorry!